# THREE.js seems to not work on localhost server

Tags: three.js

I am just starting out with THREE and have come across some odd failures which I believe are due to localhost / same-origin-poicy.

In short I created my own animation using armatures in Blender and exported using the three.js exporter plugin. The model displays but the animation doesn't run.

I used the [online skinning animation example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_animation_skinning.html) as the basis for the code and thought I may have incorrectly stripped out certain code that was causing it to fail but after looking for a couple of hours I have come to the conclusion I haven't ripped out anything incorrectly so...

To test if the example code worked locally I copied the [online skinning animation example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_animation_skinning.html) code including the buffalo.js/png files, modified the file references to map to my local copy and tried to run it in a local IIS server and all I get is the stats and no animation or model.

I checked the firebug console and only had a coupe of depreciation warnings no errors. I also checked with my model and code and I get no errors or warnings...

Anyone had this experience before? (I tested in chrome/firefox both had same behaviour)

Am happy to post code but the JSONLoader(ed) model is massive.

Thanks (and sorry for the long windedness of this SO question)

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the console warnings? Also, a link to the Blender export so we can see what version was used?

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to running things on your local machine, have you tried the steps on this wiki page? **[How to run things locally](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally)**

One example on the page suggests: `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

It's possible that your issue is related to the steps taken during your export. Without the exact errors or screenshots it's difficult to know where the issue originates from. Things to look out for:

- Is your model being exported at the first frame?
- Do you have the latest `.py` export plugin for Blender?
- Using the latest version of `Three.js`?
- Tried using `THREE.SkinnedMesh`?

Here is an article that gives you a brief overview of what is required for animated meshes within `Three.js`: **[Skeletal Animation](http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2012/01/24/from-blender-to-threefab-exporting-three-js-morph-animations/)**

This *second article* provides a much more detailed tutorial, complete with example code at the bottom of the page: **[Skeletal Animation +1](http://devmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/creating-skeletal-animation-in-blender-and-exporting-it-to-three-js/)**

Comment: Pretty sure it is exported at frame #1 (though there is a frame #0...), yes have latest .py plugin, yes latest version of three. Just to clarify I literally copied the online animation including all assets (images, scripts and json model (the bull) and ran it locally and it failed.

Comment: Could you post the error / warnings? I would need a screenshot or at least a replicated version of your code within a jsfiddle to better assist you.

Comment: ... There are no errors or warnings (in firebug). I'll cobble it together so you can test on your system.

Answer (score 1):

In order to rule out same origin policy you can actually disable the security checks chrome uses when it starts up by adding this to the target window on your shortcut properties
    --disable-web-security

see here for more information : [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)